# Does the Halfling deity Brandobaris have any known offspring?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

I'm writing an adventure that features an [Emyprean](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-e#Empyrean), who for story purposes would ideally be an offspring of [Brandobaris](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mtof/halflings-and-gnomes#Brandobaris). I'd like to know if there are any offspring of Brandobaris referenced in any of the Forgotten Realms lore. The answer need not be limited to 5th edition- if there are references from previous editions, novels or even other campaign settings, I'd like to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 6):

#### Possibly.

Brandobaris has received very little treatment in D&D sourcebooks since *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons 2nd Edition*, being only briefly mentioned, if at all.

In AD&D 2e, however, the book *Forgotten Realms: Demihuman Deities* gives Brandobaris a fairly detailed biography. There we see:

> Only Tymora regularly accompanies the Trickster on his jaunts, and Lady Luck and the Master of Stealth are said (by halflings) to be romantically linked.

Regarding Tymora, the AD&D 2e book *Faiths & Avatars* says:

> She is reputed by sages to have had short-lived romances with several
> of the good male deities of Faerûn, but these ended amicably on both sides
> after a short while.

There is nothing explicitly mentioned about Brandobaris having any children in what is, to my knowledge, the most thorough biography he has ever received in a *D&D* sourcebook. The best we can do is say that the halfling people believe Brandobaris had something of a romantic trist with Tymora.

An Empyrean offspring resulting from such a relationship seems entirely plausible.

We also see the same lore expressed in 3e's *Faiths and Pantheons*, as outlined in [Eddymage's Answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/177285/62294)

Answer (score 3):

#### The relation between Tymora and Brandobaris suggests so.

The latest information available (to the best of my knowledge) is its entry in the [Faiths and Pantheons](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Faiths_and_Pantheons) of the 3rd edition:

> A rumored romantic dalliance with Tymora may be responsible for Brandobaris's legendary luck, which plays a central role in the countless tales of daring-do traded from halfling to halfling like currency at waystations across Faerun.

Tymora's entry in the same book says (page 78):

> [...] she also retains much of Tyche's romantic fickleness - she's seduced dozen of deities and countless mortals, seldom staying with a single paramour for more than a year or two. She shares a somewhat casual, long-running romance with the halfling deity Brandobaris, whose passion for daring-do and ribald shenanigans rivals her own.

Thus, this casual relationship between the deities could have give birth to a child (or more?). Nonetheless, no official source clearly state this.

---

Actually, the name of Brandobaris is mentioned also in the 4th edition of the [Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Forgotten_Realms_Campaign_Guide) (page 81), but it is only a name in a table.

Comment: If by "the latest information", you mean "the latest information about the deity Brandobaris" (which is how I understood it, given your mention of 4e at the end)... He's mentioned in 5e, in *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*; the name "Brandobaris" in the body of the question is a link to that section of the book on D&D Beyond (though obviously you won't be able to view the linked page itself unless you own the book on DDB). That said, there's only a few paragraphs about him there, and ostensibly the querent has already read that portion and found that it contains no information on this subject.

Comment: @V2Blast Yes I am not able to see the link (I do not have the book too): indeed I wrote "to the best of my knowledge". I will try to get some access to MToF using some friend's book. Regarding the 4th edition, it is really just a line in the Exarchs table, only saying "Brandobaris, Unaligned,  male, Thievery, Green Fields, misadventurers, Brandobarian": not useful at all for the topic of requested by OP.

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to clarify that Brandobaris is indeed mentioned in 5e, just not in a way that addresses this question.